# Conditional delete rows: delete the quasi-identical rows but not the identical

Tags: r, dataframe, string-matching, delete-row

I have a data frame, and I need depurate it according with two values that are "quasi-identical" in the rows. I only need to delete the observations that differs but not the identical. I try do this using `agrep` but this function also delete the identical observations.

```
Id<-c("RoLu1976","Rolu1976","RoLu1976","AlBl1989","ThSa1996")
Art<-c("Econometric Policy Evaluation: A Critique","Econometric Policy Evaluations A Critique","Econometric Policy Evaluation: A Critique", "Rules after discretion", "Expectations and the Nonneutrality of Lucas")
Id.1<-c("FiKy1989","FiKy1989","BeBe1983","JoSt1989","JoSt1990")
Art.1<-c("Notes on the Lucas Critique","Notes on the Lucas Critique","The Inconsistency of Optimal Plans","The Inconsistency","Notes on the Lucas")
N<-data.frame(Id,Art,Id.1,Art.1)
```

The quasi identical values in the above `dataframe` is in `Art` column on the two first observation, which are different just for a `s` and `:`.

In the above case the final data frame should be (note that the identical values wasn't delete):

```
Id        Art                                          Id.1       Art.1
RoLu1976  Econometric Policy Evaluation: A Critique    FiKy1989   Notes on the Lucas Critique
RoLu1976  Econometric Policy Evaluation: A Critique    BeBe1983   The Inconsistency of Optimal Plans
AlBl1989  Rules after discretion                       JoSt1989   The Inconsistency
ThSa1996  Expectations and the Nonneutrality of Lucas  JoSt1990   Notes on the Lucas
```

What I did was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802678/r-how-delete-two-quasi-identical-rows-of-a-data-frame):

```
yy = NULL
for(i in 1:length(N$Art)){
  temp = agrep(N[i,"Art"],N$Art,value=T)
  y = ifelse(any(N[i,"Art"]==temp),temp[1],N[i,"Art"])
  yy = c(yy,y)
}
N$Art = yy
N.2 = N[!duplicated(N$Art), ]
```

But it delete both values: identical and quasi identical.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you sure you wish to base your criteria on the "Art" column only? Suppose the second row of your original `N` had "Art.1" being e.g. "Foobar" (ie different to "Art.1" of either of the other "duplicates"). Would you still want to drop it then?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee It would be two criteria: "Art" column quiasi-identical but identical in "Art.1" (or any other column) and delete all the quasi-identical values in "Art" (not the identical) but identical in "Art1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the indices of things that are identical in the original Art column, and use that in combination with the results after de-duplication, e.g.

```
originallyDuplicated <- duplicated(N$Art)
# then run your snippet to generate `yy`
```

So you want to get rid of things that are duplicated *now*, but not *originally*.

```
N[!(duplicated(yy) & !originallyDuplicated),]
```

Though to me it seems that rather than basing your exclusion criteria purely on the `Art` column, it would make more sense to exclude a row if *every column* in the row was duplicated (or almost duplicated) elsewhere in the table. (e.g. compare on the Art.1, Id.1, ID etc column too?)

Comment: This'll probably muck up if you have multiple of the same typo in `N` though (eg say you had two "Econometric Policy Evaluations") - because how will you (R) know which one is the "duplicate" and which is the "original"?

Comment: Either can serve as the "original", the problem is that --though both are "different"-- in the other columns are identical, which means that the value is counted twice.

Comment: @mathematical.cofee You are right, When the data frame have several values that are "quasi identical" it only delete one of the quasi identical values and the others values it just change to the original form.